# "Invalid connection string attribute" error comes randomly

Tags: vb6, connection-string, sqlconnection

I am using connection string as shown below in my VB6 application.But sometimes we get error like "Invalid connection string attribute". But sometimes it works properly and database connects. So why does the error come randomly? Any problem with my code or it may due to any other in network or something else?

```
connectingstr="driver={SQL Server};Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog= MyDB;Data Source=pc2\SQLEXPRESS,25111;User ID= admin;Password= password"
Set connection = New ADODB.connection
connection.ConnectionString = connectingstr
connection.Open
```

Comment: Is this always on your PC?

Comment: @No. the error is in my customers PC. It comes randomly and comes only in pc's which access SQL server through network.I mean till now error didn't came when running application in PC where SQL server database exits. Because the error comes randomly in so i doubt it may not be due to error in my connection string.

Comment: could it be a password with strange characters in it -- I see there are no quotes in your connection string to act as delimeters

Comment: @ok. which quotes you are talking about?

Comment: the quotes you don't have :) https://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/

Comment: @Rob Sorry after reading that and seeing some examples i didn't get where i am missing? Please give an example

Comment: you could have an escape character in your password (or maybe a space). In which case Password="password" would be better